# Show that in a complex Hilbert space, T normal bounded linear operator, $\| T^2 \| =\| T \| ^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, normal-operator

So,  as a part of a problem, I've been asked to prove that if $H$ is a complex Hilbert space and $T\in L(H)$ is normal,  then $\| T^2 \| =\| T \| ^2$  (Operator norm)

Context: This is part (b) in a three part problem obviously designed to build to a final result.  The final result being this is good for any integer $n$, and the first part (already proved) was that 
$$T \text { normal } \iff \forall x\in H,\| T(x)\|=\|T^*(x)\|$$

So,  here's my attempt at a proof of part b:
Since the operator norm is submultiplicative, we have $\|T^2\|\le \| T\| ^2$.
Then from a theorem in Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications (Thm 3.94(e), page 198) we have 
$$\|TT^*\|=\|T\|^2$$,
and using submultiplicativity again, combined with them 3.92 (p 196) that states $\|T^*\|=\|T\|$, we have
$$\|T\|^2\le \|T\|\cdot \|T^*\|=\|T\|^2$$
hence $\|T^2\|=\|T\|^2$  as desired.

Now, the problem is...none of theorems I have used require $T$ to be normal (Or the space to be complex).  Nor did I use part a.   So....either my proof is wrong,  or this statement actually holds for all bounded linear operators on any Hilbert space...which I doubt, so I think I made a mistake somewhere.   Any advice?

Comment: You didn't make any mistakes. The equalities $\|TT^*\| = \|T\|^2$ and $\|T\| = \|T^*\|$ hold for all bounded linear operators $T$ on a hilbert space.

Comment: @user49797 So the statement holds for any operator, not just normal ones, in any hilbert space (real or complex)?

Comment: Oh my bad, you did make a mistake. Your last inequality doesn't prove $\|T\|^2 \leq \|T^2\|$.

Comment: Woops.   Yeah,  sleep dep.  Thanks.

Comment: Friend just walked in to the office and showed me the proof,  I'm good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So,  just to formally complete this thing,  the proper proof:  Taking the square of the norms,  we have

$$\|T^2x\|^2=\langle T^2x,T^2x\rangle=\langle T^*T^2x,Tx\rangle=\langle TT^*Tx,Tx\rangle=\langle T^*Tx,T^*Tx\rangle=\|T^*Tx\|^2$$
since this holds for all $x\in H$,  we have $\|T^2\|=\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2$  as desired

(And yeah, normalcy being used!)

For those playing along with our home game, to prove this extends to any arbitray positive power $n\in \mathbb N$,  use forward/backward induction:  First it proves for arbitrary powers of 2:  $\forall k\in \mathbb N$  it holds for $2^k$  by induction on $k$. Then use backwards induction on $n$:  if it holds for $n$,  it holds for $n-1$. 
(this is only the second time I've seen forward/backwards induction used, the other time being in the proof of the arithmetic/geometric mean inequality....does anyone know of other uses?)